# in excel VBA, i do set a range and get an unexpected result?

Tags: excel, vba, range

Please see below code, this results in `$B$8`, while I am expecting `$K$2` to be the last cell address?

```
Sub GetLastCellInRange()

Dim rg As Range
Dim lastCell As Range

Set rg = Range("B3, B4, B5,J2, B6, K2")

' Get the last cell in the range
Set lastCell = rg.Cells(rg.Cells.Count)

' Get the address of the last cell
MsgBox lastCell.Address

End Sub
```

I have been trying and trying; have even asked GPTchat.........no result!

Comment: You have multiple areas, to get the last one `Set lastCell = rg.Areas(rg.Areas.Count)`

Comment: this is genius, thx a million, been messing around for hours. Will learn GPT chat the same. Thx again!!!

Comment: i got the hang of it and took it a bit further:
Set lastCell = rg.Areas(rg.Areas.Count)(rg.Areas(rg.Areas.Count).Count)